# Xcode shift+space inserts underscore in editor

Tags: xcode, editor

Does anybody know how to set up Xcode so that when I press shift+space, it inserts an underscore into the editor instead of a space?

This is just to make life easier when typing funtion_names_with_lots_of_underscores!

Comment: Generally you shouldn't be using underscores in function names but a variation of CamelCase as per the [Objective-C style guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-BCIGIJJF).

Comment: Who said I was writing Objective-C?